AT25SF081 SPI Flash to 12MHz FPGA signal timing
I am trying to understand how the timing of signals work between a 12 MHz FPGA, and a connected AT25SF081 SPI Flash device.
In my specific situation, I am trying to perform a status register read. It consists of a single 8-bit opcode sent on the SI line, and then data sent back on the SO line until CS is set back to high.
On the FPGA, I understand that after some data has been clocked out on a rising or falling edge, there is a period of time that should be respected before sampling the data so as to ensure correctness when sampling.
I believe I can use the standard clock from my FPGA to define the clock in the Flash without any adjustment, and that this should be fine - as no operation requires that the clock operate at less than 12 MHz.
On the figure 13-1 waveform, it is seems that the data on the SI line should be sampled by the flash device at least 2 nanoseconds after it is clocked out (tDS). It should then be held for at least an additional 2 nanoseconds (tDH) after the next rising edge to guarantee it is sampled.
On the figure 13-2 waveform, it seems that the data should be clocked out of the SO line no later than 7 (or 8) nanoseconds after a falling edge in order for the next sample to be valid.
Is this correct?


data on the SI line should be sampled by the flash device at least 2
nanoseconds after it is clocked out

No.  The figure 13-1 waveform means that your FPGA must assure that the SI line is stable at least 2ns before the rising edge of SCK.  If you are driving the SCK clock at 12MHz (83ns clock period), then you can change the SI signal at the rising edge of SCK and have about 42ns before the next rising edge of SCK.  You will easily meet the data setup timing requirement (tDS).
Otherwise, I think your understanding is correct.

I see. thanks! Yes so I am wondering how this works in code: 'FPGA must assure that the SI line is stable at least 2ns before the rising edge of SCK'?

Is this essentially saying that I need to use the previous negedge to define logic so that these timings are conformant to the spec?

@K_T: I think I already answered that.  The datasheet even mentions driving the signal on the falling edge of SCK.  Doing so at 12MHz, you have almost 42ns for SI to stabilize before the flash chip samples it.

Brilliant, thanks for the assistance here :)

@K_T: You're welcome.  I hope I'm helping you in this series of questions to get where you want to go.  It can be tricky communicating through websites like this.

Yes lot's of help! I really appreciate it :)
